# Copy cell values and pasting to another worksheet in a list/table

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and was recently tasked with creating a macro that copys from one worksheet containing drop-down lists and formulas to another "output" sheet that keeps these in a nice list(table) for reference.

My code was designed to do a simple copy from sheet1 and pastevalue to sheet2 and set up to search for the last cell containing data in a row and then offset it to paste below into an empty cell. This works for most of what I am trying to do but I am running into an issue where one part of the code is not pasting properly in row "J".

Here is my code:

```
Sub TestCopyToDB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("PIT Training Request Form")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Output")


copySheet.Range("C2:D2").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

copySheet.Range("C3").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

copySheet.Range("C4").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

copySheet.Range("C5").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


copySheet.Range("C6").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


copySheet.Range("C7").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

copySheet.Range("C8").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


copySheet.Range("E8").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


copySheet.Range("C11:D11").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


copySheet.Range("H16").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=xlCopy, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True




Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C3").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C4").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C5").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C6").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C7").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C8").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("C11:D11").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("E8").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("D9").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("D10").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("D14").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("D15").ClearContents
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Range("D16").ClearContents

   End With
Sheets("PIT Training Request Form").Select
MsgBox "Submission Complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

The last copy and paste line from H16 will paste but it is not finding the empty cells below and is overwriting information above it. I am not sure why.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't think you meant to include the `.Row` in `.Row.PasteSpecial` when you paste H16 to the pasteSheet.

Comment: Yeah, I was experimenting and that did not help. lol

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your code is more complicated than it needs to be. I have created some new code for you that is a lot easier. You will need to put in the actual values but I think I made it simple enough to follow.

```
Sub logInformation()
    'GET VALUES
    Dim fName As String
    Dim lName As String
    Dim age As String
    Dim gender As String

    fName = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    lName = Sheet1.Range("C2")
    age = Sheet1.Range("B3")
    gender = Sheet1.Range("B4")

    'INSERT VALUES
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim row As ListRow
    Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add
    With row
        .Range(1) = fName
        .Range(2) = lName
        .Range(3) = age
        .Range(4) = gender
    End With

    'CLEAR FORM
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Clear
    Sheet1.Range("C2").Clear
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Clear
    Sheet1.Range("B4").Clear
End Sub
```

-- OR --

You could also loop it and make it a lot easier

```
Sub logInformation()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim row As ListRow
    Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("C2", "D2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "E8", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "C16", "H16")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        row.Range(i + 1) = Sheet1.Range(arr(i)).value
        Sheet1.Range(arr(i)).Clear
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your coding and I think it will work once I wrap my head around the rows part.

Comment: You need to make your db table into a table object if you haven't already done so. To do so, select any of the cells in the table and type CTRL + L. This will turn it from normal spreadsheet to a table.

Comment: When you do `tbl.ListRows.Add`, it adds a row to the end of the table and stores the row as a variable `row`.

Answer (score 0):

A general suggestion would be to set the output range. It's a little unclear which column is "J" in your code above. It looks like your paste for that "H16" copy command is referencing **Row.PasteSpecial** which is likely the cause of your error:

```
copySheet.Range("H16").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row.PasteSpecial
```

I've looped the copying/pasting in your code above. This may be a little easier to manipulate and debug.

```
dim copyRngs as Variant, copyRng as Range, outRng as Range
copyRngs = Array("C2:D2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","E8","C11:C16","H16")
set outRng = pasteSheet.Range("A1")
For i = lbound(copyRngs) to ubound(copyRngs)
    application.screenupdating = False
    Set copyRng = copySheet.Range(copyRngs(i))
    copyRng.Copy
    outRng.Resize(copyRng.Cells.Count).Offset(copyRng.Row,End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    copyRng.ClearContents
    application.screenupdating = True
    application.cutcopymode = false
Next i
```